# How to manually set column header to datagridview with data from database

Tags: c#, datagridview

hope you can help me with this. Currently, I am working on a dynamic payroll system for our thesis which main function is to create multiple payroll format for different company. I can create simple datagridview which shows basic employee information such as Employee's "Full name" and "initial rate" but is it possible to add new header/s using a button function(not hardcoded) which will hold a value just in case the user would like to add deductibles

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and how this failed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specified platform.

In case of **WinForms**:

1. Add unbound column by click or whatever:

   ```
       var column = new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());
       column.Name = "Calculated Column";
       column.HeaderText = "Calculated Column";            
       dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
   ```
2. Add processing of datagridview.cellformatting

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Calculated Column")
       {
           var data = (DataObj)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
           e.Value = GetCalculatedColumnValue(data);
           e.FormattingApplied = false;
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Add processing of entered data in column

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Calculated Column")
       {
           var data = (DataObj)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
           SetCalculatedColumnValue(data, e.Value);
       }   
   }
   ```

P.S. I my case I use DataObj as data bounded object

```
public class DataObj
{
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

In case you need only to show external data (read only column) (p3 is not needed)